# How can I pass a file argument to my bash script using a Terminal command in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

So my question is how can I pass a file argument to my bash script using a Terminal command in Linux?
At the moment I'm trying to make a program in bash that can take a file argument from the Terminal and use it as a variable in my program. For example I run
`myprogram --file=/path/to/file` in Terminal.

## My Program

```
#!/bin/bash    
File=(the path from the argument)  
externalprogram $File (other parameters)
```

How can I achieve this with my program?

Answer (score 81):

It'll be easier (and more "proper", see below) if you just run your script as

```
myprogram /path/to/file
```

Then you can access the path within the script as `$1` (for argument #1, similarly `$2` is argument #2, etc.)

```
file="$1"
externalprogram "$file" [other parameters]
```

Or just

```
externalprogram "$1" [otherparameters]
```

If you want to extract the path from something like `--file=/path/to/file`, that's usually done with the `getopts` shell function. But that's more complicated than just referencing `$1`, and besides, switches like `--file=` are intended to be optional. I'm guessing your script *requires* a file name to be provided, so it doesn't make sense to pass it in an *option*.

Comment: Note that all parameter expansions have to be quoted, including `$file`.

Comment: Is there any way to implement the --file method? I want to do that because if it is run without the --file argument, the program could ask the user what file should be chosen. It will streamline the program that way.

Comment: Usually you just check whether the user has supplied a file name (the parameter `#` contains the number of positional arguments), and use standard input if no file or `-` was given. If you want the `--file=` syntax, use a `case` statement.

Comment: @Philipp (3 comments up): that does depend on how you want them interpreted. But in this case it probably makes sense - I just missed one accidentally. I'll edit it.

Comment: what happens when there are spaces in the file name?

Comment: @chovy then Bash will split it into multiple words on the spaces. For example, if the file name is `test file.txt` and you run `externalprogram $file`, the external program will see two arguments: "test" and "file.txt", but if you run `externalprogram "$file"`, it will see one argument, "test file.txt".

Comment: I just needed to quote it `file="$1"`

Answer (score 26):

you can use getopt to handle parameters in your bash script. there are not many explanations for getopt out there. here is an example:

```
#!/bin/sh

OPTIONS=$(getopt -o hf:gb -l help,file:,foo,bar -- "$@")

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "getopt error"
  exit 1
fi

eval set -- $OPTIONS

while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -h|--help) HELP=1 ;;
    -f|--file) FILE="$2" ; shift ;;
    -g|--foo)  FOO=1 ;;
    -b|--bar)  BAR=1 ;;
    --)        shift ; break ;;
    *)         echo "unknown option: $1" ; exit 1 ;;
  esac
  shift
done

if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "unknown option(s): $@"
  exit 1
fi

echo "help: $HELP"
echo "file: $FILE"
echo "foo: $FOO"
echo "bar: $BAR"
```

see also:

- the "canonical" example: http://software.frodo.looijaard.name/getopt/docs/getopt-parse.bash
- a blog post: http://www.missiondata.com/blog/system-administration/17/17/
- `man getopt`

links dead. here from internet archive:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20100325015445/http://software.frodo.looijaard.name/getopt/docs/getopt-parse.bash
- https://web.archive.org/web/20130827004301/http://www.missiondata.com/blog/system-administration/17/17/

Answer (score 16):

Bash supports a concept called "Positional Parameters". These positional parameters represent arguments that are specified on the command line when a Bash script is invoked.

Positional parameters are referred to by the names `$0`, `$1`, `$2` ... and so on. `$0` is the name of the script itself, `$1` is the first argument to the script, `$2` the second, etc. `$*` represents all of the positional parameters, except for `$0` (i.e. starting with `$1`).

An example:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"
externalprogram "$FILE" <other-parameters>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, in this case where we expect `$1` to contain a filename it should be quoted to avoid word splitting, should the filename contain one or more spaces. But is quoting positional parameters *always* necessary?

Comment: I think it's easier to always quote all variables than to guess whether they have to be quotes. Positional arguments are user input, and users can enter anything, so unless it is documented that an argument undergoes word splitting it must be quoted. Technically, variables don't have to be quoted after `=` and within `[[...]]`, but again it's easier to quote them than to remember where word splitting is not performed.

Comment: @Philipp: Good points. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you do as David Zaslavsky suggests, so that the first argument simply *is* the program to run (no option-parsing required), you're dealing with the question of how to pass arguments 2 and on to your external program. Here's a convenient way:

```
#!/bin/bash
ext_program="$1"
shift
"$ext_program" "$@"
```

The `shift` will remove the first argument, renaming the rest (`$2` becomes `$1, and so on).`$@` refers to the arguments, as an array of words (it must be quoted!).

If you must have your `--file` syntax (for example, if there's a default program to run, so the user doesn't necessarily have to supply one), just replace `ext_program="$1"` with whatever parsing of `$1` you need to do, perhaps using getopt or getopts.

If you want to roll your own, for just the one specific case, you could do something like this:

```
if [ "$#" -gt 0 -a "${1:0:6}" == "--file" ]; then
    ext_program="${1:7}"
else
    ext_program="default program"
fi
```

Comment: +1 for quoting. But neither `getopt` nor `getopts` can parse GNU style arguments.

Comment: @Philipp: getopts can't, but getopt definitely can, on my system anyway. Presumably that comes from the fact that there's both a GNU and non-GNU version of the C function `getopt`.